# Making use of an index on a VARCHAR2 field where the VARCHAR2 is a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table that has a LETTER_SENT date field. The LETTER_SENT is a varchar2 field, and is a text string of yyyymmdd (so 20140708 indicates that the letter was sent on July 8, 2014). Note: This isn't my table, I only have grants to SELECT on it so I can't force it to a yyyymmdd date.

Frequently, I need to look for letters sent in a range of dates. Usually, I do WHERE IN ('start date', ..., 'end date'). From what I understand about SQL, doing it this way doesn't tinker with the field in any way which won't impact the use of the index (whereas converting to date or number and then doing a comparison would impact the index).

Performance wise, this is fine. However, sometimes my date ranges are quite large and having a gargantuan IN, ...OR IN, ... OR IN clause in the WHERE statement is ugly as sin.

Is there another, syntactically prettier, but still performant way to do date comparison in the where clause (date between date_begin and date_end) when the date is an indexed varchar2?

Comment: Have you tried doing `letter_sent >= '20160101' and letter_sent <= '20160430'`? I wonder how an indexed string containing such numbers extracts data. Perhaps it is performant - I don't know. Just curious if you have attempted that.

Comment: @zedfoxus This works vastly better - I can't believe I forgot this works! Please post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it, smacking my head that I forgot this.

Comment: Tom Kyte had a very convincing conference presentation (I saw a link in a thread on OTN once) - he showed concrete examples for how an index on a `VARCHAR2` column supposed to encode dates performed very poorly compared to an index on a proper `DATE` column - for exactly the same data (other than the different data type for this column). Don't use `VARCHAR2` for dates; this is one of the more than 100 excellent reasons for that.

Comment: Here's a very simply example. Imagine there two dates. The optimizer will attempt to generate a cardinality estimate of the number of rows. When stored as VARCHAR2.  20170101 - 20161230  is 8871. When in actual fact the value should be 1.

Comment: @Joe I have added my answer and also included the same recommendation that other commenters are providing - that of using a date field instead of varchar2 for long term effectiveness.

Comment: You might see if a pragmatic compromise is to create a function-based index on the expression to_date(column,'YYYYMMDD') -- you could run tests on a different system on which you have the required permissions to see if it can improve cardinality estimates where the range crosses a month or year boundary.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thats simply the wrong answer. Just piling more wrong on top of wrong.

Comment: @bobc It's a comment aimed at seeking pragmatic, maybe temporary, compromise, and it suggests a route of investigation if the most appropriate and (trivially) obvious fix is not currently possible. Insisting that a change of datatypes is the *only possible correct course of action* does not help the OP find a solution to the problem he is faced with.

Comment: @DavidAldridge. I understand what you are saying. However this type of situation is probably the second highest in terms of category of escalation into my group. The customer is unhappy, blaming the database for poor performance; claims of losing $$$ etc etc. We both know that this "fix" will not be temporary. The problem today is seen as "solved". At some point in the future, there is a high probability of more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an index on the varchar2 field, I believe that you will be able to use a query like so:

```
select * from tablename
where letter_sent >= '20160101' and letter_sent <= '20160430'
```

The text may be treated sequentially and you may get the desires results with the use of an index.

Long term, it would be effective to create `letter_sent_date` as a date field, update this field using data from `letter_sent` and then deprecating `letter_sent`. You will gain benefits from using date-centric functions like `year(letter_sent_date)` instead of needing to cast the varchar2 field to date and then apply function.

Comment: @Joe - There will be uncountable other benefits, too. Imagine how easy it is to determine if a follow-up letter was sent within 10 business days from the initial one, if dates are in `varchar2` data type!

Comment: It'd be great to know why the answer received a downvote. I'd like to know if this answer can be improved.

Comment: Downvoted because of encouraging "bad behaviour". The customer should use the correct datatype. See answer below. See also my comment/example above as to why this is bad.

Comment: @BobC Gotcha. I appreciate it. My intent was to provide immediate relief knowing the situation OP is in, and with the recommendation to use date datatype in my last paragraph. I do appreciate your comment and will keep it in mind going forward.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to store LETTER_SENT using a DATE datatype, not VARCHAR2(). You will be much better off in terms of syntax, the use of index(es), correctness of results, optimizer statistics and ultimately performance.

Comment: Trust me, I know - this isn't my table :/. I do not know why the table creators chose to do it this way. I'll edit the original to reflect that. Regardless, upvoting so anyone coming later sees how to not do it :)

Comment: @Joe. I **highly** encourage you to go back to the table creators and get this fixed. I have lost count to the number of escalations because of this. In addition, you will be implicitly disabling Oracle optimizations because of type conversions. Any if the creators refuse; go to their manager !!

Comment: I'll mention it to them, but I don't expect anything to change. Big companies move glacially and change nothing.